# how to use mvn command line property to define the project's name

Tags: properties, command, version, line, artifact

I want to add a suffix (like JIRA ticket number) to the project's name through command line,so i get an artifact like Artifact-1234.jar when building the project.
I tryied passing a parameter using -Dsuffix=1234 and used that parameter in pom.xml like

```
    <build>
    <finalName>Artifact-${suffix}</finalName>
```

but this did not work and the project is generating a jar with name Artifact-null.jar.
Also maven complains about this solution not been recommended:

> [WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @line 10, column 14
>   [WARNING] The expression ${version} is deprecated.
>   Please use ${project.version} instead. [WARNING] [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
>   [WARNING]
>   [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

Any idea of how i can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem solved,  all i had to do is to define the property under properties tag

```
</properties>
    <prefix></prefix>
</properties>
```